# How to identify the Json syntax to obtain a value

Tags: json, powershell

I need help to construct the right syntax to reach the value highlighted in the picture below.

The attached picture shows the JSON structure, but I am not able to write the correct syntax to reach the value "7:00".

I have tried this code, but no sucess.

```
$WebHookData = @"
    {"source":"la-draft-clipboard","value":[{"tokenKey":"8EAD3F03-E08F-4D58-8B1A-2AB8BD2F25DB","type":"literal","tokenExpression":"{"},{"tokenKey":"A7596123-17DF-49A9-AC18-1196A4CD457E","type":"new_line","tokenExpression":"\n"},{"tokenKey":"36DF511D-C1A9-4BC8-B2E9-37BCA058FB78","type":"literal","tokenExpression":" \"AutomationAccountName\": \"proj-00016-automation-account\","},{"tokenKey":"918137AE-EC61-4B77-A5F2-B527E2D4E3C9","type":"new_line","tokenExpression":"\n"},{"tokenKey":"DCC2D1C1-14F0-4869-A44C-08F8AB35B0B3","type":"literal","tokenExpression":" \"BeginPeakTime\": \"7:00\","},{"tokenKey":"61F7441B-0688-4AD2-A1A5-086C4F7F6D1E","type":"new_line","tokenExpression":"\n"},{"tokenKey":"2F3DD3CA-BD83-46EF-9529-C890C2E31CAF","type":"literal","tokenExpression":" \"ConnectionAssetName\": \"AzureRunAsConnection\","},{"tokenKey":"C6DD6FD0-E99A-48A8-96AA-3974D66FD9BD","type":"new_line","tokenExpression":"\n"},{"tokenKey":"A4E7A469-D08A-4C5A-8C6B-06E58996A0EC","type":"literal","tokenExpression":" \"EndPeakTime\": \"17:00\","},{"tokenKey":"E67547BC-98BB-4749-A84E-A36B761EE504","type":"new_line","tokenExpression":"\n"},{"tokenKey":"727D64BD-906C-4DA3-84C5-44F3054B2DEB","type":"literal","tokenExpression":" \"HostPoolName\": \"VDI-POOL-001\","},{"tokenKey":"92AFEBB8-4307-42C2-8BD0-C55ACC848940","type":"new_line","tokenExpression":"\n"},{"tokenKey":"F37993F9-1471-4E58-B43F-9BB08C4D4A03","type":"literal","tokenExpression":" \"LimitSecondsToForceLogOffUser\": 0,"},{"tokenKey":"8B2517D1-046E-43EF-BF75-B1EC5F31B83D","type":"new_line","tokenExpression":"\n"},{"tokenKey":"7464316E-6A8D-4F82-B269-95FF76A69014","type":"literal","tokenExpression":" \"LogOffMessageBody\": \"Salve seus trabalhos! Em aproximadamente 15 minutos, este terminal virtual será desligado automaticamente devido às políticas de otimização de custos da companhia. Caso seja necessário continuar suas atividades, um novo terminal poderá ser acessado após este período.\","},{"tokenKey":"7328955E-0025-4AA1-A0AE-CDAFA4238927","type":"new_line","tokenExpression":"\n"},{"tokenKey":"384AF3CF-CA86-4820-A5E1-230C09909662","type":"literal","tokenExpression":" \"LogOffMessageTitle\": \"ATENÇÃO!!!\","},{"tokenKey":"5E2EBD78-8599-487F-8DC5-CF9699595DDD","type":"new_line","tokenExpression":"\n"},{"tokenKey":"B7E409AF-A5AE-4622-A45E-5982FD15B03E","type":"literal","tokenExpression":" \"MaintenanceTagName\": \"NO_TAG\","},{"tokenKey":"3F9BF963-790D-45B1-9F04-D71A2B7C84DC","type":"new_line","tokenExpression":"\n"},{"tokenKey":"B6E94E37-69C0-4BF8-AE69-CD7B4EA9CB83","type":"literal","tokenExpression":" \"MinimumNumberOfRDSH\": 20,"},{"tokenKey":"00A1D37B-F82B-42F6-B792-75B39EBD6A83","type":"new_line","tokenExpression":"\n"},{"tokenKey":"F41B0C75-4541-4772-BF30-2D4F6DF045C6","type":"literal","tokenExpression":" \"ResourceGroupName\": \"proj-00016-wvd-rg\","},{"tokenKey":"FE6FC329-DC12-4782-83CE-F48BDC6B74B5","type":"new_line","tokenExpression":"\n"},{"tokenKey":"785500F8-3D71-4D91-AADA-D6ABF1EFD66B","type":"literal","tokenExpression":" \"ResourceGroupNameAutomation\": \"proj-00016-automation-rg\","},{"tokenKey":"BD3331BF-3BF9-4B9E-B9B8-C03E448B2D85","type":"new_line","tokenExpression":"\n"},{"tokenKey":"25586050-62A0-4CAF-81FD-C5770DF20B63","type":"literal","tokenExpression":" \"RunbookLogoffShutdown\": \"ARMLogoffAndShutdown\","},{"tokenKey":"C4B9E432-C41D-4374-9531-F2AEFDD51267","type":"new_line","tokenExpression":"\n"},{"tokenKey":"0155B6AB-7CAB-4C4E-BB1F-A643D9B0575B","type":"literal","tokenExpression":" \"SessionThresholdPerCPU\": 0.75,"},{"tokenKey":"3EAA1C7E-0119-40B9-9AF8-85D10E0FA3FD","type":"new_line","tokenExpression":"\n"},{"tokenKey":"2D904698-1386-47D7-9513-7CEE702BA0D3","type":"literal","tokenExpression":" \"TimeDifference\": \"-3:00\""},{"tokenKey":"40D497B6-AAED-4334-81C7-10B8C6745DE0","type":"new_line","tokenExpression":"\n"},{"tokenKey":"18EB90AF-25D4-4956-8A85-41BA555C6A95","type":"literal","tokenExpression":"}"}]}
"@ | set-content jsonfile.json1

$json1 = (Get-Content "jsonfile.json1" -Raw) | ConvertFrom-Json


$aa = $WebHookData.source.value[0]

Write-Output $aa
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just trying to view all of `tokenExpression` in the `value` array:

```
$json1.value.tokenExpression
```

If you're trying to get the `BeginPeakTime` value, you'll need to use some regex to do that:

```
$peakTime = $json1.value.tokenExpression |
    Where-Object { $_ -match 'BeginPeakTime.+?(\d+:\d+)' } |
    ForEach-Object { $Matches[1] }

$peakTime
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this, I'm not sure if the item you're looking for specifically contains the words *"BeginPeakTime"*:

```
$peaktime = $json1.Value.where({
    $_.tokenExpression -match 'BeginPeakTime.*"(?<peaktime>[\d:]+)"'
})
```

Then if you inspect the automatic variable [`$Matches`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#matches):

```
PS /home/> $matches

Name                           Value
----                           -----
peaktime                       7:00
0                              BeginPeakTime": "7:00"

PS /home/> $matches['peaktime']

7:00
```

And the variable `$peaktime` contains the matched element:

```
tokenKey                             type    tokenExpression
--------                             ----    ---------------
DCC2D1C1-14F0-4869-A44C-08F8AB35B0B3 literal  "BeginPeakTime": "7:00",
```